# Don't run function until .hide() has finished its animation

Tags: javascript, callback, hide

I have a table that is updated by AJAX. When an item is deleted, I want for the item to be hidden first, and then for the table to be updated.

I thought this could be achieved with `.hide()` (example below), but the function `inlineEditEvent.update_table()` is being run instantly, and not waiting for the animation to complete.

Does anybody know what I need to do to make it so that the function doesn't fire until `hide()` has finished it's animation? Thanks.

```
$(t.what+id).hide({
    duration: 800,
    done: inlineEditEvent.update_table() // Have also tried 'complete'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the callback function reference to `done`, not the value returned by `update_table` by invoking it( adding `()` at the end of a function name will invoke it)

It should be

```
$(t.what+id).hide({
    duration: 800,
    done: inlineEditEvent.update_table
});
```

if you want to pass any data

```
$(t.what+id).hide({
    duration: 800,
    done: function(){
        inlineEditEvent.update_table(1, 2, 3)
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. One minor issue now though - I need to pass some variables to the callback. Is that possible through this method?

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't work with `done`, but with `complete` it works just fine. Thanks for the help.